# Strings look the same but test says they are different

Tags: java, string

I have some code which is effectively the following:

```
String a;
String b;
a = get_string_from_complex_procedure_1();
b = get_string_from_complex_procedure_2();
if (a != b)
{
    put_up_error_dialog("["+a+"] != ["+b+"]");
}
```

The code is designed such that a and b *should* end up identical, and indeed most of the time they are, but occasionally I get the error dialog appearing. The confusing thing though, is that the two strings *appear* identical to me when reported by the dialog. I'm wondering what sort of things can cause this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of *lots* of posts comparing strings using `==` or `!=`. Those only compare *references*. Use `equals` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I guess you will always get lots of duplicates for this question because it is not obvious what to search for. I was suspecting all sorts of subtle things like unicode vs ASCII characters or some such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite like this:

```
String a;
String b;
a = get_string_from_complex_procedure_1();
b = get_string_from_complex_procedure_2();
if (!a.equals(b))
{
    put_up_error_dialog("["+a+"] != ["+b+"]");
}
```

The `==` and `!=` operators compare references, not values.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `==` and `!=` on Strings. To compare two Strings use `a.equals(b) and !a.equals(b)`

Answer (score 0):

Use of `==` or `!=` in case of String compares reference (memory location) so better you use `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
       a.equals(b); or  a.equalsIgnoreCase(b) to compare String.
```